# How to handle labels when using the BERTs' wordpiece tokenizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

I am trying to do multi-class sequence classification using the BERT uncased based model and tensorflow/keras. However, I have an issue when it comes to labeling my data following the BERT wordpiece tokenizer. I am unsure as to how I should modify my labels following the tokenization procedure.

I have read several open and closed issues on Github about this problem and I've also read the BERT paper published by Google. Specifically in section 4.3 of the paper there is an explanation of how to adjust the labels but I'm having trouble translating it to my case. I've also read the official BERT repository README which has a section on tokenization and mentions how to create a type of dictionary that maps the original tokens to the new tokens and that this can be used as a way to project my labels.

I have used the code provided in the README and managed to create labels in the way I think they should be. However, I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it. Below is an example of a tokenized sentence and it's labels before and after using the BERT tokenizer. Just a side-note. I have adjusted some of the code in the tokenizer so that it does not tokenize certain words based on punctuation as I would like them to remain whole.

This is the code to create the mapping:

```
bert_tokens = []
label_to_token_mapping = []

bert_tokens.append("[CLS]")

for token in original_tokens:
   label_to_token_mapping.append(len(bert_tokens))
   bert_tokens.extend(tokenizer.tokenize(token, ignore_set=ignore_set))

bert_tokens.append("[SEP]")
```

```
original_tokens = ['The', <start>', 'eng-30-01258617-a', '<end>', 'frailty']
tokens = ['[CLS]', 'the', '<start>', 'eng-30-01258617-a', '<end>', 'frail', '##ty', '[SEP]']
labels = [0,2, 3, 4, 1]
label_to_token_mapping = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Using the mapping I adjust my label array and it becomes like the following:

```
labels = [0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1]
```

Following this I add padding labels (let's say that the maximum sequence length is 10) and so finally my label array looks like this:

```
labels = [0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

As you can see since the last token (labeled 1) was split into two pieces I now label both word pieces as '1'.

I am not sure if this is correct. In section 4.3 of the paper they are labelled as 'X' but I'm not sure if this is what I should also do in my case. So in the paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805) the following example is given:

```
Jim    Hen    ##son  was  a puppet  ##eer
I-PER  I-PER    X     O   O   O       X
```

My final goal is to input a sentence into the model and as a result get back an array which can look something like [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]. So one label per word piece. Then I can reconstruct the words back together to get the original length of the sentence and therefore the way the prediction values should actually look like.

Also, after training the model for a couple of epochs I attempt to make predictions and get weird values. For example a word is marked with the label '5' for padding and padding values get marked with the label '1'. This makes me think that there is something wrong with the way I create labels. Initially I did not adjust the labels so I would leave the labels as they were originally even after tokenizing the original sentence. This did not give me good results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been trying hard to find what I should do online but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. Thank you in advance!

Also, the following is the code I use to create my model:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf


class BertLayer(tf.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, bert_path, max_seq_length, n_fine_tune_layers=10, **kwargs):
        self.n_fine_tune_layers = n_fine_tune_layers
        self.trainable = True
        self.output_size = 768
        self.bert_path = bert_path
        self.max_seq_length = max_seq_length

        super(BertLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.bert = hub.Module(
            self.bert_path,
            trainable=self.trainable,
            name="{}_module".format(self.name)
        )
        trainable_vars = self.bert.variables

        # Remove unused layers
        # trainable_vars = [var for var in trainable_vars if not "/cls/" in var.name]
        trainable_vars = [var for var in trainable_vars
                          if not ("/cls/" in var.name) and not ("/pooler/" in var.name)]

        # Select how many layers to fine tune
        trainable_vars = trainable_vars[-self.n_fine_tune_layers:]

        # Add to trainable weights
        for var in trainable_vars:
            self._trainable_weights.append(var)

        for var in self.bert.variables:
            if var not in self._trainable_weights:
                self._non_trainable_weights.append(var)

        super(BertLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        inputs = [K.cast(x, dtype="int32") for x in inputs]
        input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids = inputs
        bert_inputs = dict(
            input_ids=input_ids, input_mask=input_mask, segment_ids=segment_ids
        )
        result = self.bert(inputs=bert_inputs, signature="tokens", as_dict=True)[
            "sequence_output"
        ]
        return result

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0], self.output_size

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'bert_path': self.bert_path, 'max_seq_length': self.max_seq_length}
        base_config = super(BertLayer, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))


# Build model
def build_model(bert_path, max_seq_length):
    in_id = Input(shape=(None,), name="input_ids")
    in_mask = Input(shape=(None,), name="input_masks")
    in_segment = Input(shape=(None,), name="segment_ids")
    bert_inputs = [in_id, in_mask, in_segment]

    bert_output = BertLayer(bert_path=bert_path, n_fine_tune_layers=3, max_seq_length=max_seq_length)(bert_inputs)
    dense = Dense(128, activation='relu')(bert_output)
    pred = Dense(8, activation='softmax',)(dense)

    model = Model(inputs=bert_inputs, outputs=pred)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
    model.summary()

    return model


def initialize_vars(sess):
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    K.set_session(sess)
```

Comment: Have you tried using run_classifier.py directly?

Comment: To be honest with you I have not. I'm using the model as a layer through tensorflow hub. I've updated with the code that I use to create my model.

Comment: Well, If it is just sentence classification (binary or multiclass), I don't really think that you must manually tokenise it. However, I am uncertain. As,I use the run_classifier.py directly and pass the required parameters.

Comment: Do check out: https://appliedmachinelearning.blog/2019/03/04/state-of-the-art-text-classification-using-bert-model-predict-the-happiness-hackerearth-challenge/          and         https://mc.ai/a-guide-to-simple-text-classification-with-bert/



I found them helpful

Comment: It is not sentence classification but word level classification. In fact my output is not pooled but sequenced.

Comment: My issue is that I've found a lot of tutorials on doing sentence level classification but not word level classification. After further reading I think the solution is to label the word at the original position with the original label and then the words that have been split up (usually starting with ##) should be given a different label (such as 'X' or some other numeric value)

Comment: I think its hard to perform the word level tasks, if I look at the way the bert is trained and the tasks on which it performs well, I do not think they have pre-trained on word level task. Also, section 4.3 discusses 'name-entity' recognition, wherein it identifies if the token is the name of a person or the location, etc. (Here, it is possible that all the pre-trained tokens that belong to the name of a person may have similar embeddings, and likewise for the names of the places )

Comment: Hmm okay, thanks for your help. I'll keep trying because I don't want to give up on it yet. I've tried performing my task using a bidirectional LSTM and did not get good results which is why I'm trying to use BERT as I think an attention model is more appropriate for my task. Any, other form of help relating to my issue with bert would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: To be frank, even I have got very low accuracy on what I have tried to do using bert. Anyways, please let the community know, if it worked and your solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Just read that bert used token level classification on SQuAD task, just check if it helps you.

Comment: I will check it out! thanks for the info

Comment: @D. Gal, did you find a solution? I have the exact same problem. Not sure if I should tag all the WordPiece tokens.